# Can I pour a concrete footing on very wet base material?

Tags: concrete, footings

I'm ready to pour a concrete footer for a small retaining wall.  The footer will be 8' x 1' x 6".

I spread and, with a plate compactor, compacted 6" of crush and run which will be below the concrete footer.  It rained all day yesterday. I had a 10x10 pop-up canopy over the area, but it still managed to get wet.

When I walk on the gravel it is noticeably squishy and shifts with my weight.

Is it OK to pour the concrete on this, or should I wait until it is more stable and re-compact?

Comment: what kind of retaining wall? Note that stacked walls often don't need concrete footers. Properly prep'ed and compacted crushed rock should suffice (and may even be preferable depending on climate).

Answer (score 1):

I'd wait. You said a footer for a retaining wall. If the wall is 4' high or more and only holding back earth (no car or house surcharge,) then the footing should be about 3' wide. Also, the rebar should be on the side of the wall closest to the earth.

The force from the earth will push on the wall and will make the wall and footer ROTATE about the footing. If this soil under the footing is soft, it will compact the soil and cause the wall to lean.

By the way, don't forget to install a perf pipe at or near the bottom of the footing encased in drain rock.